# setting up ssh keys for cr-48

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, google-chrome-os, cr-48

I have a cr-48 chromebook. I'm here in crosh. I'm trying to ssh into my server so i can work remotely.

Anyone know if theres an easy way to setup ssh-key's? 
So i could possibly just ssh without a password? Or if google stripped out this functionality. According to the manual it looks like this command isn't packed into the chrome os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice if you go to crosh and type 'ssh' then 'help' one of the options listed allows you to specify a keyfile:

```
key <file>
```

It also states "Key files must reside in /media or /home/chronos/user. Key files in the Downloads directory may be specified with an unqualified name."

I don't believe there is currently a utility to generate keyfiles, unfortunately.